# how to get value from the fckeditor texfield

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

i have put fckeditor in jsp page. I want to get the value whatever we write on the editor textarea. I have put the code below in my jsp page.

As we all know that getting value of text field like

is done by writing 
String title = request.getParameter("title1");

in the same way i want the value from the fckeditor..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation of FckEditor which request parameters it sends to the server side and use HttpServletRequest#getParameter() the usual way.

If you don't want to put effort in reading the documentations for some reasons, you can also read all request parameters using HttpServletRequest#getParameterMap() so that you can learn which parameters FckEditor sends and finally apply this knowledge in the final coding.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.net we use: `fckEditor1.Value`

I think in jsp you can use `fckEditor1.getValue()`

These pages may help you further:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12467

http://my.opera.com/mattroiden3012/blog/using-fckeditor-in-jsp-web-pages

http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/Java

Comment: ASP.NET is a component based MVC framework while JSP is just a view technology, like ASP (without dotnet) is. The difference is quite big. Sun's ASP.NET's counterpart is JSF/Facelets.